# Possible bug: The system tells me to select a reason even though I've already done so

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen, review-queues

I recently reviewed a question in the "reopen votes" queue. I wanted to keep the question closed because it was a single-word request but did not include sufficient information about how the word would be used. I therefore clicked the appropriate reason to keep it closed and then clicked "keep closed". However, I got an error saying that I needed to select a reason before submitting. (See screenshot below.) I tried this a couple of times but kept getting the same error. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: [MSO dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/6083675) — it's status-review.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for finding that! (I'd only searched on ELU Meta.) It was asked 2 days ago, so I guess that this issue came up recently and is site-wide and that TPTB are aware.